# To access controls of a form from a different project in same solution

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want access controls in a form which is in a different project in the same solution.I have designed in a such a way that one solution has different projects in it.

I have tried the following code.

```
           Form form =  (Form)Application.OpenForms["frm"];
           if (form != null)
           {

             Button cs = (Button)((form.Controls["btn"]);
               cs.Enabled = false;
           }
```

Using this code am able to locate the form,but am not able to access controls from it."cs" is returning null value and throwing "null refernce exception error".What could be the possible error and how should I modify the code.Its a windows application using c# visual studio 2010.
Any suggestion would be of great help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring why you might want to do this in the first place, I would recommend:

1. Add the first project as a reference to the second
2. Add a public property to the form you need to access to controls from
3. Get the form as you currently are
4. Cast the form to its appropriate/actual type
5. Use the public property.

Comment: Hi,I am not able to add reference since its showing "Circular Dependency Error"

Comment: If project 1 requires project 2 AND project 2 requires project 1 you have designed this application badly. (Poorly would be too nice) Learn about dependencies and either combine both projects into one, or actually learn the concepts you are trying to implement. (If you do the 2nd option, the answer to your question becomes obvious, and if you do the first option, its not an issue in the first place, but you show that you do not understand OOP at all) {Sorry for the late response}

Comment: Thank u for the late response